# How to pass props to screens in TabNavigator?

Tags: react-native, material-ui, react-navigation

How do I pass props to my screen components in TabNavigator? And with that I mean FindDestinationScreen.
I would like to somehow have a HOC that wraps `<AppContainer>` and passes props to my screens.

Ive tried different solutions that people has answered to similar questions here but can't get it to work..

Here is my code and this is my app.js:

```
import { SafeAreaView, View } from "react-native";

import { createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";
import { createMaterialBottomTabNavigator } from "react-navigation-material-bottom-tabs";

import Icon from "react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons";

import FindDestinationScreen from "./src/screens/FindDestinationScreen";
import CurrentTripScreen from "./src/screens/CurrentTripScreen";

const TabNavigator = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    FindDestinationScreen: {
      screen: FindDestinationScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        title: "Search",
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
          <SafeAreaView>
            <Icon
              style={[{ color: tintColor }]}
              size={25}
              name={"ios-search"}
            />
          </SafeAreaView>
        )
      }
    },
    CurrentTripScreen: {
      screen: CurrentTripScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        title: "Trip",
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
          <SafeAreaView>
            <Icon style={[{ color: tintColor }]} size={25} name={"ios-train"} />
          </SafeAreaView>
        )
      }
    },
  {
    shifting: false,
    labeled: true,
    initialRouteName: "FindDestinationScreen",
    activeColor: "#ffffff",
    inactiveColor: "#000",
    barStyle: { backgroundColor: "#456990", height: 80, paddingTop: 10 }
  }
);

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(TabNavigator);

export default App = () => {
  return <AppContainer />;
};
```

**What I want to happen**: Let's say that if I write `<AppContainer testProp="testString" />`. Is it possible to retrieve this prop in the screens written in TabNavigator? I mean is it possible to access the prop if I write it in some other way?

**What I have tried:** I have tried the code above and also just the prop in TabNavigator like so `<FindDestionationScreen testProp="testString">`
This works but I dont want to write this on every screen.

Comment: Question needs some more info on what props you are trying to pass. What solutions you have tried till now. One way you can access data in screen using redux and there are many other ways to do that also.

Comment: Yea sry about that. I have updated the question.
Like you said, I can use redux etc. One thing I really wanted to use is Context API. But the question remains, How to I wrap an ContextProvider around all the screens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use Context API, create your context, and wrap your root app component/AppStack with the provider then you can have access to all states in any of your screens/pages by using useContext hook. For example;

```
<ImageProvider>
    <FoodProvider>
      <EventProvider>
        <AppProvider>
          <AppStack/>
        </AppProvider>
      </EventProvider>
    </FoodProvider>
  </ImageProvider>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: So you think I can use my AppContainer instead of AppStack and it still works?

Comment: Yes in your case that would work for you. Give it a try and let me know.

Comment: Ah that was correct. I did an context that wrapped my appContainer and props succesfully goes to my screens. Awesome. Thanks for the help but stupid of me not to have tried it before.

Comment: Awesome. No that is all good. We all learned it that way, so you never forget. No worries. Anytime.